# PHP contact form not redirecting

Tags: php, html

I have built a PHP contact form on wordpress that redirects user based upon his/her selected region.

I have used 'www.google.com' as a test URL.

However, the form is not getting redirected and staying on the same page after submitting.

Where am I going wrong?

Please find the code below:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $region = $_POST['Region'];
   switch ($region )
  {
        case 'North': $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
        case 'South': $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
        case 'East':  $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
        case 'West':  $url = 'https://www.google.com/'; break;
    }
  if(!empty($url))
  { header('Location: '+ $url);
     }
  }
 ?>
 <html>
  <head>
    <title> Meal Planner </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" method="POST">
        <p>Name</p> <input type='text' name='cp_name'>
        <p>Email</p> <input type='text' name='cp_email'>
        <p>Phone</p> <input type='text' name='cp_phone'>
        <p>Dropdown Box</p>
        <select name='Region' size='1'>
            <option value='North'>North
            <option value='South'>South
            <option value='East'>East
            <option value='West'>West
        </select>
        <br />
        <input type='submit' name="submit" value='SUBMIT'><input type='reset' value='CLEAR'>
    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the url is not correct.

The `+` sign is for concatenating strings in javascript language. You should use `.` sign.

```
header('Location: ' . $url);
```